# ~/.inputrc file not sourcing correctly

Tags: bash, tcsh, readline

I have this ~/.inputrc file that I created for certain key bindings.

```
# mappings for Ctrl-left-arrow and Ctrl-right-arrow for word moving
"\e[1;5C":forward-word
"\e[1;5D":backward-word
"\e[5C":forward-word
"\e[5D":backward-word
"\e\e[C":forward-word
"\e\e[D":backward-word
```

whenever I try to run `source ~/.inputrc`, it gives me the following error:

> \e[1;5C:forward-word: Command not found.
>   \e[1;5D:backward-word: Command not found.
>   \e[5C:forward-word: Command not found.
>   \e[5D:backward-word: Command not found.
>   \e\e[C:forward-word: Command not found.
>   \e\e[D:backward-word: Command not found.

It also doesn't work when I open a new terminal, I don't get the error but my ctrl key combinations are not working in new terminal as well. I created this file myself since I do not have root access to change /etc/inputrc. Can anybody help me out? Thanks.

EDIT: I've tried the file with space after the colon (:) sign as well. It doesn't work. I also tried my making it executable (chmod +x ~/.inputrc), didn't work.

EDIT: I realized that this procedure is only for 'bash' and I am running 'tcsh'. For 'csh', use `.bindings` file instead of `.inputrc` file and use `bindkey` syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key bindings and `~/.inputrc` file posted in question is for `bash`. For `csh` (or `tcsh`) use a file `~/.bindings` and use following syntax.

```
bindkey '^[[1;5C' forward-word
bindkey '^[[1;5D' backward-word
```

Realized this after some googling.

Comment: For whatever reason, my tsch was ignoring the .bindings file. Adding `source ~/.bindings` to my `~/.cshrc` file fixed this.

Comment: @drmuelr, if you need to do a `source`, you may as well have called the file `.bindkeys` (or any other name as a matter of fact). I have the same issue as that my tcsh (version 6.17 does not automatically source the .bindings file). Maybe @rrlamichhane can comment on what tcsh version he is using ?

Answer (score 16):

For bash, this will reload now the currently defined mappings

```
bind -f  ~/.inputrc
```

Comment: Where to get the `bind` command from?

Comment: bind is a shell builtin. What os are you running?

Comment: I'm using Debian with zsh.

Comment: this did not work for me with bash on RHEL 7. My .inputrc bindings are still not re-loading after running this command.

Comment: @user5359531, could it be that your previous bindings are not "un-loading"?  (If they're not set explicitly, they'll remain as they were before.)  Or maybe something else, like your ~/.inputrc doesn't `$include /etc/inputrc`?

Answer (score 7):

The `.inputrc` file is not a file to be sourced. It should be taken into account automatically by `bash` or other software using the readline library. If this doesn't work, add a space after the colon, e.g.

```
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
```

(I've always seen a space in this config file).

Comment: +1 Emphasis on "other software using the readline library". `.inputrc` is not a shell script; it's a `readline` configuration file.

Comment: Actually, that's how I had it first and I changed it to without space just to try it out. It doesn't work either way. I've added that in the edit. Thanks.