# How do I auto complete a command from the command history?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, command-history

Is there a key combination for bash to auto compete a command from the history? In ipython and matlab for example this is achieved by pressing up arrow after typing a few characters.

Comment: If you have brought the command up with `Ctrl-r`, then you only need to press `Enter` to execute it...

Comment: the question appears to be a duplicate of [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5366/command-line-completion-from-command-history), [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/308603/auto-complete-for-often-used-command-line-commands) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030182/how-do-i-change-bash-history-completion-to-complete-whats-already-on-the-line).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

First of all, hitting <kbd>tab</kbd> in bash is even better since it autocompletes all executables in your PATH irrespecitve of whether they're in the history. That said, there are various ways of getting a command from your history:

1. Use its number. If you know that the command you want was 3 commands ago, you can just run

   ```
    !-3
   ```

That will re-execute the command you ran three commands ago.

2. Search for it. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> and start typing any text. The first command from the history that matches your text will be shown and hitting <kbd>enter</kbd> will execute it.
3. Hit <kbd>▲</kbd> (up arrow). That will bring up the last command, press it again and you will go up your command history. When you find the one you want, hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.
4. Add these lines to your `~/.inputrc` (create the file if it doesn't exist):

   ```
    "\e[A": history-search-backward
    "\e[B": history-search-forward
   ```

To immediately load the file, run `bind -f ~/.inputrc` ([source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/246422)). Now, type the first few characters of one of the commands you've previously run and hit <kbd>▲</kbd>. The first command from your history that starts with those characters will be shown. Hit <kbd>▲</kbd> again to see the rest and hit <kbd>enter</kbd> when you've found the one you want.

4. Use the `history` command. As @Isaac explained, that will list all of the commands stored in your history file.

Comment: #4 is exactly what I needed. #2 is also cool, but #4 comes more natural to me.

Comment: oh, I missed your answer #2 ... I'll delete my answer

Comment: #2 matches anywhere in the history line, makes it very nice to find "the few last commands where I operated on THISSERVER" : THISSER[ctrl+r] (and additionnal Ctrl+r to find the older occurences in your history)

Comment: it's also possible to _first_ type ABC and _then_ press [ctrl]+[r], which might me more natural for some users

Comment: on [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/308603/auto-complete-for-often-used-command-line-commands) they also recommended adding `set show-all-if-ambiguous on` and `set completion-ignore-case on` to `~/.inputrc`.

Comment: @Sparkler thanks but neither seems relevant. They both affect tab completion, not history. The second is not even a good idea depending on how you use your machine (I don not want my shell completion to be case insensitive!)

Comment: In case of #4 answer (the most useful to me), use GNU screen or tmux to open another window in case of a typo in your bash setup files... Then `exec bash -l` to restart your bash without closing your current screen or tmux window.

Answer (score 8):

You can check the command position on the history sequence with the command `history`. Then you can execute `!<number_in_the_sequence>`. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `history` and pipe the output for a specific command.

For example, if you've been `cd`-ing all around the file system all day and just need a reminder of what directories were worked on

```
history | grep cd
```

You could then either copy/paste the command, or `!n` (where n is the line number in history file) to re-execute it.