# inputrc not working in ubuntu 18 as it used to in 16 and below

Tags: inputrc

I used to create a simple `.inputrc` in my users directory and add the following:

```
"e[A": history-search-backward
"e[B": history-search-forward
"e[C": forward-char
"e[D": backward-char
```

reload bash

```
exec bash -l
```

And then be easily able to traverse the bash history with the arrow keys.

Now in ubuntu 18 the same does not work.. i don't know if it is not reading the inputrc file or something else.. anyone else had the same issue and found a resolution?

i also tried from this answer [~/.inputrc file not sourcing correctly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153357/inputrc-file-not-sourcing-correctly?rq=1#answer-246422)

```
bind -f  ~/.inputrc
```

But this still is not working for me.. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that the key bindings need a backslash "\". But I can't tell if that's all you need. I'm on Debian.

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
"\e[C": forward-char
"\e[D": backward-char
```

Here is an example how you can check if a binding is active.

- check if history-search-backward is set

  ```
  $ bind -p|grep history-search-backward
  # history-search-backward (not bound)
  ```
- test which command has key sequence "\e[A"

  ```
  $ bind -p|grep "\\e\[A"
  "\e[A": previous-history
  ```
- write new key binding to ~/.inputrc and reload

  ```
  $ echo '"\e[A": history-search-backward' >> ~/.inputrc
  $ bind -f ~/.inputrc
  ```
- check again if history-search-backward is set

  ```
  $ bind -p|grep history-search-backward
  "\e[A": history-search-backward
  ```

Comment: the backslash was the resolution! thank you